# Let postfix reject unauthenticated emails from my own domain

Tags: linux, smtp, postfix

I have an email server running on Debian11 with postfix. I have strict restrictions implemented (SPF, DKIM, ...) to prevent spam.
Works fine so far.

But recently I just realized every guy with a valid reverse hostname can send with a spoofed sender address from my own domain to accounts of my own domain.

So an email from unknownuser@mydomain.com to realuser@mydomain.com from an IP with a valid reverse hostname is getting accepted.
Obviously this is something I do not want- I want my postfix to allow only authenticated users to send with mydomain.com as sender.

Is there a simple fix for this? I can not believe it is so easy to trick postfix nowadays :|
I found a similar [question and answers](https://superuser.com/questions/964958/make-postfix-reject-incoming-email-spoofed-as-from-my-own-domain) to this issue here, but it has been eight years ago and the solution is not as "quick-and-easy" as I was looking for.

So the main question:
**Is there a more recent solution to the issue?**

Here's the main part of my main.cf:

```
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
        reject_unknown_helo_hostname
smtpd_client_restrictions =
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_unknown_client_hostname,
        reject_rbl_client ix.dnsbl.manitu.net,
        reject_rhsbl_client dbl.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rhsbl_reverse_client dbl.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rbl_client psbl.surriel.com
smtpd_sender_restrictions = 
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain,
        reject_unknown_client_hostname,
        reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_invalid_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        reject_unauth_pipelining,
        check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/access,
        check_policy_service unix:private/policy
        check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023
```